# An ordinary differential equation similar to Bessel Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I need to solve the following differential equation:
$$u'' + \frac{1}{x}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\log x}\right)u' + \left(1 - \frac{n^2}{x^2}\right)u = 0.$$
It is similar to the Bessel equation but the term $\frac{1}{x\log x}$ with $u'$.
I intend to transfer it to Bessel equation by some substitution but I have no idea.
Thank you very much for your help.